Turtlebot3 3 Omni wheels
I'm working on a project , where I would like to control A 3 Omni wheels turtlebot3 from ROS2 , I've downloaded all the pacakge but for the waffle version ( because Omni isn't a standard version like burger and waffle ) , now I would like to adjust those files So I can control my Omni 3 wheels turtlebot3, any ideas (UDRF...)??
